# Make query to return matrix

Tags: mysql

I have a table that describes a distances matrix. It's like this

```
idOrigin idDestiny distance
 0          0         0
 0          1         1
 0          2         2
 1          0         1
 1          1         0
 1          2         1
 2          0         2
 2          1         1
 2          2         0
```

I'm looking to return the data like this

```
0 1 2
1 0 1
2 1 0
```

Where the rows represent the idOrigin, and the columns the idDestiny.

Is there a way to get this output? either with pure MySQL?

Comment: are you trying to take the distance column and split it up? its hard to understand what you're trying to get.

Comment: I'm trying to map each distance in their proper row and column. For example for example origin: 50, destiny:4, distance 30. Would go to row 50, column 4 with a value of 30

Comment: where do you get the origin 50 destiny 4.. etc... whats the requirement?

Comment: It's all stored in the same table. In that case idOrigin=50, idDestiny=4, distance=30. All the origins/destinies are consecutive starting at 0. And of course when idOrigin = idDestiny then distance = 0.   It's a way to store a matrix, the table is useful like this for us, but now I need to visualize the matrix that was originally stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a row of comma separated `destination` values for each group of `idOrigin` values where the `destination` values are ordered by `idDestiny` by using `group_concat`. This assumes that the table being selected from doesn't have any missing coordinates otherwise an incorrect matrix is produced.

```
select group_concat(destination order by idDestiny)
from mytable
group by idOrigin
order by idOrigin
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45fde4/3

Comment: I have to validate that I'm not missing some origin, destiny index in the original table, but this works. Thanks